# Multi monitor display stops working when testing Kernel 5.5-rc1 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: nvidia, kernel, multiple-monitors

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.  Kernel 5.5 should address/fix a problem with certain hardware on my system.  I would like to test for this and load the 5.5-rc1 kernel for a short period of time.

Using the Ubuntu Kernel Update Utility, I am able to boot my system with Kernel 5.5-rc1 running.  Most everything seems to work fine, however I lose multi-monitor support.  My system only seems to detect one monitor connected while running 5.5-rc1.  What can I do so multiple connected monitors are detected on my system?

When I revert back to kernel 5.0x, multimonitor works as expected.  If it matters, I am using an nvidia card with nvidia drivers installed.

Comment: It's a RC (release candidate) kernel, so testing for problems with is it's current purpose. Your issue with the RC kernel should be reported.

Comment: I also believe making changes to work around a RC could be a waste of time, if bugs are reported for that kernel, they'll get fixed and a RC2 will get released - your 'fixes' could cause problems with that next version, or were just a waste of time.

Comment: While searching a bit more, it appears I may have to update/install nvidia kernel modules when I'm running a newly installed kernel.  If anyone has any best practice guide for accomplishing this, please let me know.